# API documentation for Sitecore 6

Tags: api, documentation, sitecore

Is there any good API documentation available for Sitecore?

I mean something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.aspx

But for Sitecore specific classes?

I know about their SDN site and have an account there, but cannot seem to find anything more useful than a lot of PDF files describing specific topics in depth (Documentation Package).

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's [a number of CHM files](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Sitecore_6_API_Reference.aspx) for various Sitecore 6.X versions. Besides, there are more API description and samples of specific areas, like [Security API](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/62/security_api_cookbook_sc60-62-a4.pdf) and [Engagement Analytics API](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/engagement_analytics_api_reference_guide_sc65-a4.pdf). See [the reference page](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Well, it's like with everything - once you know where it is it's easy to find ;-) Thanks

Comment: None of those links work.

Comment: @AllanHorwitz, that's unfortunate... I'll try to find the locations of those resources and update the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AllanHorwitz, fixed.